# Running a Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to run my Flask app on a Bokeh server using the following command as recommended by the instructions:

```
bokeh serve --show myapp
```

I have also added this code to my script, as recommended:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
from helpers import load_data

load_data(join(dirname(__file__), 'data', 'things.csv'))
```

Instructions: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#userguide-server-applications

What is this '`from helpers import load_data`' module?

Comment: That is one place where you would put your own code - in the example, they move all the loading data code into another file, helpers.py and import the function. This would allow you to keep the main file more concise

Comment: Perhaps it was not as clear as it could be in the docs. That code snippet is intended to be merely suggestive of typical usage, not demonstrative of any specific, actual use case or code. i.e., "typically a user would load their data here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `helpers` is not of prime interest, `load_data` is.

It is a function that you will have to create on purpose to load data from, say, a csv file, and which returns a [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). For example it could be something like

```
import pandas as pd    

def load_data(filepath):
    return pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0)
```

And then

```
load_data(
    filepath=join(dirname(__file__), 'data', 'things.csv')
)
```

---

One way of making this [example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#userguide-server-applications) yours, would be to define your own script `helpers.py` within your working directory, and then within this script, to define the function `load_data` as shown above.

Comment: Any question @AnnaBernbaum ?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that makes much more sense! I have lots of CSVs in my data folder, do I need to call 'load_data' for every single one?

Comment: @Anna can't you merge all your CSVs in a first preprocessing phase?

Comment: I will still have 2 separate ones for different types of data

Comment: @Anna Then you would have to load your two CSVs within `load_data` and return them as one dict object whose keys would be presented to users in a select-menu box. Probably better to precise this point with a new question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'presented to users'. I am currently trying to run the bokeh server from the terminal but get the error 'Expected a '.py' script or '.ipynb' notebook, got: Users/...' instead.

Comment: @Anna. Do not hesitate to post a new question, above all not forgetting to copy/paste the entire error message you get. The community will be very glad to help you.